# Regex : How to reorder comma separated values alphabetically

Tags: regex, string, firebase, alphabetical

I'm trying to store some firebase IDs, they come as a single string separated by a comma, and each may start with a non-alphabet character.

```
var IDs = "-sdfasdf34552ghkjhghk,Fg3dffghdfghjksfgs";
```

So with the above, the stored value will result in being :

```
"Fg3dffghdfghjksfgs, -sdfasdf34552ghkjhghk"
```

I'll be using String.matches() in firebase. So the regex must also be able to support those features. https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/api/string/matches.html

If this is possible, How would I start writing this sort of thing?

Comment: Split-Sort-Join.

Answer (score 0):

You can't sort with regular expressions, they are not made for that.

Instead you should try one of the following :

- Use the sorting instruction of your language.
- Make your own sorting algorithm that will work on your data

Comment: If that's the case then I'll have to find another way to sort it since I can only use regex for this in Firebase.

Comment: Don't you communicate with firebase using JavaScript (or sth else)?

Comment: I do, also on Android. I used IDs.sort().join(",") on Javascript. But then since this is on the user, it can be changed. And if this could be done on the server, there wouldn't be a need to sort it on every client.